# how to lock an asp.net mvc action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've written a controller and action that I use as a service.
This service runs quite a costly action.
I'd like to limit the access to this action if there is already a currently running action.

Is there any built in way to lock an asp.net mvc action?

Thanks

Comment: Would you like to limit it per user, per session, per application?

Comment: You are looking for queues.

Comment: overall limitation, don't allow anyone to enter if it has been called

Comment: by "if it has been called" you meant "if it is in execution"

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public MyController : Controller
{
    private static object Lock = new object();

    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            // do your costly action here
        }    
    }
}
```

The above will prevent any other threads from executing the action if a thread is currently processing code within the `lock` block.

**Update: here is how this works**

Method code is always executed by a thread. On a heavily-loaded server, it is possible for 2 or more different threads to enter and begin executing a method in parallel. According to the question, this is what you want to prevent.

Note how the `private Lock` object is `static`. This means it is shared across all instances of your controller. So, even if there are 2 instances of this controller constructed on the heap, both of them share the same Lock object. (The object doesn't even have to be named Lock, you could name it Jerry or Samantha and it would still serve the same purpose.)

Here is what happens. Your processor can only allow 1 thread to enter a section of code at a time. Under normal circumstances, thread A could begin executing a code block, and then thread B could begin executing it. So in theory you can have 2 threads executing the same method (or any block of code) at the same time.

The `lock` keyword can be used to prevent this. When a thread enters a block of code wrapped in a `lock` section, it "picks up" the lock object (what is in parenthesis after the `lock` keyword, a.k.a. `Lock`, `Jerry`, or `Samantha`, which should be marked as a `static` field). For the duration of time where the locked section is being executed, it "holds onto" the lock object. When the thread exits the locked section, it "gives up" the lock object. *From the time the thread picks up the lock object, until it gives up the lock object, all other threads are prevented from entering the locked section of code. In effect, they are "paused" until the currently executing thread gives up the lock object.*

So thread A picks up the lock object at the beginning of your MyAction method. Before it gives up the lock object, thread B also tries to execute this method. However, it cannot pick up the lock object because it is already held by thread A. So it waits for thread A to give up the lock object. When it does, thread B then picks up the lock object and begins executing the block of code. When thread B is finished executing the block, it gives up the lock object for the next thread that is delegated to handle this method.

**... but I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for...**

Using this approach will not necessarily make your code run any faster. It only ensures that a block of code can only be executed by 1 thread at a time. It is usually used for concurrency reasons, not performance reasons. If you can provide more information about your specific problem in the question, there may be a better answer than this one.

Remember that the code I presented above will cause other threads to wait before executing the block. If this is not what you want, and you want the entire action to be "skipped" if it is already being executed by another thread, then use something more like Oshry's answer. You can store this info in cache, session, or any other data storage mechanism.

Comment: shouldn't lock be persisted into a session or cache object as well?

Comment: Why do you think it would need to be persisted to session or cache?

Comment: since http is session-less, I'd need to save the lock throughout the sessions, no?

Comment: HTTP may be sessionless, but server methods are executed by threads. Session is merely a data storage mechanism. Your HTTP request is handled by the server and a thread is pulled from the pool to execute your server-side method. You do not need session, cache, or any other data storage mechanism to prevent other threads from executing a method after another thread has entered it, but before the other thread has exited it. This type of thread-based method locking is built into the server runtime. I will update my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Does using the lock ensure that all calls to the method will eventually run, and requests will run in order each time the lock is released? Using a queue and processing outside of the action isn't necessarily suitable for my use case, or rather isn't desired if a lock will achieve what we need

Answer (score 11):

I prefer to use [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) because it support async operations.

If you need to control the read/write then you can use the [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim).

The following code snip uses the `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim ProtectedActionSemaphore =
        new SemaphoreSlim(1);

    [HttpGet("paction")] //--or post, put, delete...
    public IActionResult ProtectedAction()
    {
        ProtectedActionSemaphore.Wait();
        try
        {
            //--call your protected action here
        }
        finally
        {
            ProtectedActionSemaphore.Release();
        }

        return Ok(); //--or any other response
    }

    [HttpGet("paction2")] //--or post, put, delete...
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProtectedActionAsync()
    {
        await ProtectedActionSemaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            //--call your protected action here
        }
        finally
        {
            ProtectedActionSemaphore.Release();
        }

        return Ok(); //--or any other response
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Shouldn't the static var be `new SemaphoreSlim(1,1)`? i.e., you should also specify `maxCount` to be `1` as well to have the same effect as `lock`

Comment: @fullStackChris You can set the `maxCount=1`, I've ignored it because both functions are waiting for the semaphore before call the `.Release()`, it means you will never allow more than 1 item concurrently. Please read a bit more about this constructor [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_SemaphoreSlim__ctor_System_Int32_)

Answer (score 6):

Having read and agreed with the above answer I wanted a slightly different solution:
If you want to detect a second call to an action, use Monitor.TryEnter:

```
if (!Monitor.TryEnter(Lock, new TimeSpan(0)))
{
    throw new ServiceBusyException("Locked!");
}
try
{
...
}
finally {
    Monitor.Exit(Lock);
}
```

Use the same static Lock object as detailed by @danludwig

Comment: I Try Same Way . But have Problem

while (!Monitor.TryEnter(LockObj))
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(50);
                        }
try{
...
}
finally {
    Monitor.Exit(LockObj);
}

Comment: because "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code"

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom attribute like `[UseLock]` as per your requirements and put it before your Action

Answer (score 2):

i have  suggestions about that.

1- https://github.com/madelson/DistributedLock
system wide lock solution

2- Hangfire BackgroundJob.Enqueue with     [DisableConcurrentExecution(1000)] attribute.

Two solution are pending for process to be finished. i don't want to throw error when request same time.

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way to do that would be save to the cache a Boolean value indicating the action is running the required BL already:

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["IsProcessRunning"])
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["IsProcessRunning"] = true;
    // run your logic here
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["IsProcessRunning"] = false
}
```

Of course you can do this, or something similar, as an attribute as well.

Comment: you could have the two threads getting together inside the if condition. this isn't good enough I fear

Comment: How can you get two threads getting together inside the if condition?
It's practically impossible, but if you must be absolutely sure, you can lock the assignment to the cache.

Comment: This is recipe for a very dirty race condition bug. If anything bad happen if two threads execute the same thing, use a lock.

Comment: This doesn't prevent the race condition where 2 or more threads execute the IF at the same time before the variable changes to true.