# Where to Initialize Static Properties in an MVC Model & Implementing a Lock

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, static

I'm trying to loosely implement my own 'lock' or 'mutex' for my website. To do this, I'm using an `isLocked` property to let the server know whether or not another user is running the update. I want to initialize its value once but I'm not sure if my solution will do that. Here's the complete example:

In the model:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public static bool isLocked = false;
}
```

Where I'm using the property:

```
public class OtherModel : BaseModel
{
    public OtherModel() : base()
    {
        if (/*condition &&*/ !BaseModel.isLocked)
        {
            BaseModel.isLocked = true;
            //update
            BaseModel.isLocked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Will the server initialize `isLocked` once (the first time BaseModel is instantiated) or do I need to set its value in the **Global.asx** file?

Edit: [This was shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901048/how-to-lock-an-asp-net-mvc-action/13902435#13902435) by @Michael which explains the solution in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the server will initialize isLocked once.  However, you have a bigger problem.  There is a race condition here.

It's possible that between the time when you check whether isLocked is true and time you set isLocked to true, another thread may be checking isLocked as well and find it false, and you both might set it to true and think you both have the static locked.

This is why you should not use methods like this to do locking.  Instead use a static object, and then the c# lock statement on that object, like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public static object lockObject = new Object();
}

lock(Model.lockObject)
{
   // do something...
}
```

If you need to test if the code is locked, then use Monitor.TryEnter.

```
if (Monitor.TryEnter(Model.lockObject))
{
    try
    {
        // use object
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(Model.lockObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: @christo8989 - your updates don't change anything.. you still have the race condition, you still need to use an atomic locking operation.

Comment: I get it. I will try this. Thank you! (I re-edited the edit to fix the names...)

Comment: @christo8989 - you just have to be careful that you lock a static object, if you don't and lock something that is a local, then you will only be locking a variable that only that thread can see and will defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're not using the `lock` statement around the code you wish to lock?

e.g.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public static Object Lock = new Object();
}        
public void Update()
{
    lock (ViewModel.Lock)
    {
        //Perform updates
    }
}
```

You can view a good answer already related to using `lock` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13902435/4488780) instead of me repeating what has already been answered.

Comment: I thought lock was for a single process.

Comment: @christo8989 - Yes, it is.. and?  You can't access your ViewModel from a different process anyways.