# Get sequence number thread safely

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a ASP.NET application where I use a sequence number from a database sequence when creating a record in a table with entity framework. I have a stored procedure that retrieves the next value in this sequence that is called from entity framework and I want to ensure that this retrieval is thread-safe.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13902435/1662372) answer to attempt this in the following class:

```
public static class SequenceNumber
{
    private static object Lock = new object();

    public static long Next(Context db)
    {
        long next = 0;

        lock (Lock)
        {
            next = db.GetNextComplaintNumber().Single().Value;
        }

        return next;
    }
}
```

Will this ensure thread-safety?

Comment: For what? for the scope of `GetNextComplaintNumber` yes, but any thread calling `Next` will be mixed up with other threads. If you want to ensure that `GetNextComplaintNumber` is only called once at the same time you should rely on database transaction handling instead.

Comment: A database sequence should always give a unique number so calling it so there should be no problems calling it from multiple threads, what is it you think can go wrong?

Comment: @Manr101: i need all numbers to be incremented by 1 exactly and with one number never being skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Next(...) method will be threadsafe but the db.GetNextComplaintNumber() will not be (unless it is implemented to be). The lock ensures that any thread calling Next(...) will have to wait their turn to run whatever is in the lock statement. However if any other threads have access to the object db then they could effectively call db.GetNextComplaintNumber() without calling the Next(...) method so it would not be protected by the lock statement. If you can guarantee db.GetNextComplaintNumber() is only called in the Next(...) method then you should be safe, otherwise you would want to implement thread safety into the db.GetNextComplaintNumber() method.

Comment: Ok, this will work. The idea of this class is for it to be the only point where GetNextComplaintNumber() in the EF context is accessed. Thanks