# Asp MVC: one action at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application in asp mvc 5.
Is possible to execute one POST action one user at a time?
I have

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Book(int? id)
{
    //Algorithm
    //Code
    ...
    ...
}
```

If two user call this action nearly in the same time, how can i permit that this action is executed for user A and then for user B?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901048/how-to-lock-an-asp-net-mvc-action ?

Comment: not sure i follow. have you come across a scenario where the website can't handle simultaneous requests?

Comment: my website can handle simultaneous request, but i need that one action is executed sequentially

Comment: @rogerdeuce 's link will work if your action isn't too long - otherwise 2nd/3rd user will think your application has died (and maybe refresh/repost multiple times etc).   You might like to implement a queue, for which there are multiple solutions (static queue / save to db with service app picking up requests / etc)

Comment: @Tom  the linked question answers your question

Comment: Note the caveat in the linked answer.  It *does* achieve the described behavior, but as others have also pointed out this may not be what you *actually* want to do.