# Is this a suitable usage of lock in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, locking, opayo

I have an ASP.NET MVC project that takes payments via SagePay (Using Jeremy Skinnners SagePayMVC solution).  The solutions also using Entity Framework with the UnitOfWork pattern.

When a SagePay payment has completed SagePay calls back on a notification URL.
This is an action on my SagePay controller which looks something like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Notify(SagePayResponse response)
{
        using (UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            if (ResponseLegit(response,unitOfWork))
            {
                SavePaymentToDatabase(response,unitOfWork);      
            }
            unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

On the whole this seemed to work - but every now and then we'd end up with multiple payments in the database.  It seemed that if the server was particularly busy it could take slightly too long to respond and so SagePay would send out a second notification (or sometimes even several).

So my first attempt to prevent this happening was to add a check to see if a payment already existed that matched the transaction number for the payment.

```
    Order order =GetRelatedOrderFromSagePayResponse(unitOfWork,response);
    bool paymentAlreadyExists = PaymentExistsForOrder(order, response);
    if (!paymentAlreadyExists)
    {    
       SavePaymentToDatabase(response,unitOfWork);    
    }
```

However that didn't work.  Multiple payments continue to show up now and then.

So what I think is happening is that the server is busy on some other unknown task, the notifications from SagePay start queuing up, IIS then catches up and hands a thread to each of the requests - such that they are handled in parallel. As such the check is negated as entity framework has populated the objects from the database at the same time and there's no  payments at the time it checks them.

So I'm thinking a solution would be to use the Lock method as in this question here:
[how to lock an asp.net mvc action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901048/how-to-lock-an-asp-net-mvc-action)

```
   private static object NotifyLock= new object();

   [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult Notify(SagePayResponse response)
    {
          lock (NotifyLock)
          {
            using (UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
            {
                if (ResponseLegit(response,unitOfWork))
                {
                    Order order=GetRelatedOrderFromSagePayResponse(unitOfWork,response);
                    bool paymentAlreadyExists = PaymentExistsForOrder(order, response);
                    if (!paymentAlreadyExists)
                    {    
                         SavePaymentToDatabase(response,unitOfWork);    
                    }
                }
                unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
            }
         }
    }
```

Is this a legitimate usage of Lock and will it stop multiple notifications entering the Notify action at the same time, and thus allow my multiple payments check to work?

Comment: This sort of lock will not help if you ever scale out to multiple web servers. Secondly, I'm not sure your logic is correct - I doubt SagePay would send out multiple requests like that. Are you sure the user isn't just pressing the submit button twice or something else is the issue?

Comment: The submit payment button is provided by SagePay and the notify can only be called by SagePay.  Only the notify action creates the payment our end - so I'm fairly certain this is what is happening.

The reason I believe they send out multiple notifications is because the user's screen is waiting to be redirected to the success action our end- which can only happen once the notification has returned successfully.  If the notification times out at SagePays end then I think they try again.  However I think the timeout window must be very small.

Comment: I would get in touch with SagePay to confirm that, but I'm certain that's not how it works.

Comment: http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/38/server-integration-the-notification-post

"1 Notification POST per 1 second for 10 seconds"

Comment: Oh, this is server integration, now I get it. So you really just need to cope with multiple posts. Can't you put an index in the DB to prevent multiple rows per payment being added? Sounds like something that would be useful anyway.

Comment: Thanks - it would seem if this had been done this from the start that would have been a good solution.  It's not looking easy to do that with several years of data in the table (not all of which is related to SagePay) .  I'd want to use the IGNORE_DUP_KEY option to prevent exceptions being thrown when the duplicates are created.  However you can't use IGNORE_DUP_KEY with filtered constraints/indexes, and there's too much data which violates the constraint at present.  All fun!  Might have to fix this in stages...